# How to collapse a div with jQuery without a id

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of questions and answers grouped in different divs. I would like to collapse them when a click event is fired that is placed on the question. I have read the examples from the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) page but I would like to tricker the event with Javascript and not with data-attributes. With data-attributes every question needs a unique id and this will hard to maintain in the future. I want to trigger the class ".collapse"

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grdnA

Comment: Please mention clearly click on which element should trigger which element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. You can always modify it according to the element being watched for click and the element to toggle.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/pF7A9/)

You can use `slideToggle()` instead of `toggle()` to get the collapsing effect.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Remember to include jQuery library

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div.panel').find('.collapse').toggle('')
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GmUqh/)